# Jquery - Hide/Show qustion

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
  $("p").hide(1000);
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
  $("p").show(1000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

It has 2 buttons (for show & hide) and content to show/hide . I want to do the following modification , but i have no experience in jQuery so i need help  :

1)Instead of hide button , I want to hide the content on the page load .

2) After showing the content "Clicking show" , I want to redirect the user into another page within 10 seconds If applicable . If i can't do this i want to show a button after 10 seconds

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide(1000);

  $(".showContent").click(function(){
      $("p").show(1000);
      window.setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = "http://google.com";}, 10*1000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button class="showContent">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1970090 No worries, good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 3):

**To hide** it from start you can do it thru CSS (though I advise to give a class or ids to those `<p>` you wanted hided).

With CSS: `p {display:none}` or with jQuery `$("p").css( "display", "none" );`

**To redirect** them to a new window after 10sec (same as 10.000 milisec) do:

```
$(".btn2").click(function(){
  $("p").show(1000);
  setTimeout(function (){window.open('myurl.com', '_blank' )}, 10000);
  });
```